# Test domain assumption of a variable

Tags: assumptions

Using `$Assumptions` to define the domain of variable is straightforward, i.e. `$Assumptions = Element[x, Reals]`. Nevertheless, it's not clear how to test this assumption and return a True, False answer.  The documentation seems to indicate that the statement `Element[x, Reals]` will return True if x is already defined as a member of Reals but I don't seem to be able to get this output consistently. Is there another way to test the domain assumptions of a variable?

Comment: `$Assumptions=Element[x,Reals]; Simplify[Element[x,Reals]]` returns `True`

Comment: `$Assumptions` only affect functions that use the option `Assumptions`.  `Simplify` is typical: its default options include `Assumptions :> $Assumptions`